# How to show that the Nearest Neighbour Algorithm given an instance of the metric travelling salesman problem has a logarithmic approximation ratio?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I would like to understand why the Nearest Neighbour Algorithm has a logarithmic approximation ratio when given an instance of the metric travelling salesman problem. I have come across the paper of Rosenkrantz et al. : https://disco.ethz.ch/courses/fs16/podc/readingAssignment/1.pdf

What I have difficulty in is Lemma 1 in this paper in the part where the lower bound $\sum_{i \in H} \alpha_i l_i$ $\geq$ 2 $\sum_{i = k+1}^{min(2k, n)} \alpha_i l_i$ is given. Can anyone help in clarifying where this lower bound has come from? Why is it assumed in the paper that the first $k$, $l_i$'s have $\alpha_i$ = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k$ is at least half of the number of edges in $T$, otherwise $H$ would not be a complete subgraph on the node set. To obtain a lower bound now, we can just choose the $\alpha_i$ suitable.

$$\sum \alpha_i l_i = a_0 l_0 + \ldots + a_kl_k + \ldots + a_{\min(2k,n)} l_{\min(2k,n)}
= 0 l_0 + \ldots + 0l_k + \ldots + 2 l_{k+1} + \ldots + 2 l_{\min(2k,n)}$$

Comment: but why are we assuming that $\alpha_i = 2 $ $\forall$ $i \geq k+1$?

Comment: The $\alpha_i$ have to sum to the number of edges in $T$ and can be at most 2. Therefore if we set all $\alpha_0, \ldots, \alpha_k = 0$ we must set the rest of them to 2 so they add up to $2\cdot (\min(2k, n) - k -1)$

Comment: Though I think it must be shown that the lower bound holds for any configuration of the alphas. Though, since this holds other cases are trivial.

Comment: I think another important issue not mentioned in the paper is that the $l_i$'s must be positive.